# how i can save an integer from a class and use it in another class

Tags: java, android

i have 2 classes , inputHandlerMenu and GameWorld , and i want to get an integer from inputHanlerMenu and use it in GameWorld ! it tried a lot but i didnt work . can any one help me ?

i declared  : public GameWorld seter;

```
 @Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    screenX = scaleX(screenX);
    screenY = scaleY(screenY);

    if (menuButtons.get(0).isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
        world.getMenuObject().getPad().end();
        seter.setModes(1);
       for (int i = 0; i < menuButtons.size(); i++) {
            menuButtons.get(i).end();
        }
        world.getMenuObject().getVolumeButton().end();
        menuButtons.get(0).tranToGameScreen();


    }if (menuButtons.get(1).isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
        world.getMenuObject().getPad().end();
        seter.setModes(2);
       for (int i = 0; i < menuButtons.size(); i++) {
            menuButtons.get(i).end();
        }
        world.getMenuObject().getVolumeButton().end();
        menuButtons.get(1).tranToGameScreen();

    }if (menuButtons.get(2).isTouchUp(screenX, screenY)) {
        world.getMenuObject().getPad().end();
        seter.setModes(3);
         for (int i = 0; i < menuButtons.size(); i++) ....
```

i declared mode as public int mode;

```
 public void setModes (int mode){
    this.mode = mode;
}

private void collisions() {
    {
        if (!ball.hasCollided()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < pad.getcolCircles().size(); i++)
                if (Intersector.overlaps(pad.getcolCircles().get(i), ball.getColCircle())) {

                    ball.collide();
                    ball.setCollided(true);
                    //Gdx.app.log("Angle", ball.getVelocity().toString());
                    //double perp = 2.0 * ball.getVelocity().cpy().dot(pad.returnNormal(i));
                    //Vector2 reflectDir = ball.getVelocity().cpy().sub((pad.returnNormal(i).scl((float) perp))).scl(1);
                    float newAngle = getAngle2Vecs(ball.getVelocity(), pad.returnNormal(i));

                    //Gdx.app.log("Angle", newAngle + "");
                    ball.setVelocity(new Vector2(gameWidth / 2 - ball.getColCircle().x, gameHeight / 2 - ball.getColCircle().y));

                    int rand = (int) Math.random() * 90 + 5;
                    if (pad.getAngularVelocity() < 0) {
                        ball.setVelocity(ball.getVelocity().cpy().rotate((float) (rand + Math.random() * 50)));
                    } else if (pad.getAngularVelocity() > 0) {
                        ball.setVelocity(ball.getVelocity().cpy().rotate((float) (-rand - Math.random() * 50)));
                    } else {

                        ball.setVelocity(ball.getVelocity().cpy().rotate(Math.random() < 0.5 ? -rand : rand));

                    System.out.println(mode);

                    if (mode == 1) {
                        if (score <= 5) {
                            ball.setVelocity(ball.getVelocity().cpy().scl(Configuration.E_VELOCITY_OVER_0));
                        } else if (score >= 5 && score < 50) {
                            ball.setVelocity(ball.getVelocity().cpy().scl(Configuration.E_VELOCITY_OVER_5));
                        } else if (score >= 10 && score < 50) {
                            ball.setVelocity(ball.getVelocity().cpy().scl(Configuration.E_VELOCITY_OVER_10));
                        } else if (score >= 20 && score < 50) {
                            ball.setVelocity(ball.getVelocity().cpy().scl(Configuration.E_VELOCITY_OVER_20));
                        } else if (score >= 35 && score < 50) {
                            ball.setVelocity(ball.getVelocity().cpy().scl(Configuration.E_VELOCITY_OVER_35));
                        } else if (score >= 50 && score < 75) {
                            ball.setVelocity(ball.getVelocity().cpy().scl(Configuration.E_VELOCITY_OVER_50));
                        } else if (score >= 65 && score < 75) {
                            ball.setVelocity(ball.getVelocity().cpy().scl(Configuration.E_VELOCITY_OVER_65));
                        } else if (score >= 75 && score < 100) {
                            ball.setVelocity(ball.getVelocity().cpy().scl(Configuration.E_VELOCITY_OVER_75));
                        } else if (score >= 100 ) {
                            ball.setVelocity(ball.getVelocity().cpy().scl(Configuration.E_VELOCITY_OVER_100));
                        } ....
```

i use for every button her mode , like if he pressed button 0 , velocity will change , button 1  => velocity change ...

here the int stay at 0 . it doesnt change !

any one know how to do it ! ?

Comment: You should pass the values to the activity. Setting values  to a model class in one and getting that in other wont work...

Comment: You can declare the variable as `protected static`, instead of `public`. Then refer it prefixing the name of the containing class. I.e.: `score = Class1.intValue + 5;`

Comment: idk how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your GameWorld class and make sure mode is public int

```
public int mode;

public int getModes(){
return mode
}
```

Now in your other class whenever you need the integer simply call

```
int getthatint = seter.getModes();
```

Comment: make sure to initialize the class when you start your activity so you don't have to make a new instance of it whenever you need data.  If you do that It will work.

Comment: wich class ? and how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences and store the integer value in Input Handler Menu and then you can get the value in GameWorld as shown below.

In Input Handler:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putInt("Key" , your_int_value);
                    editor.commit();
```

In GameWorld:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           int position = sharedPreferences.getInt("key", Default_Value);
```

The integer value stored will be assigned to position, you can use that where ever you want.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: check the edit. I have changed String position to int position since you are getting int value. Sorry had  missed that.

Comment: do i have to create a new class SharedPreferences ?

Comment: No in your existing class you can use this

Comment: @SPECIAL REVIEWS did you try this

Comment: This is very simple technique where ever you need you can use this

Comment: i did it but it says error http://puu.sh/gzMBJ/284d860820.png do you know how to solve this ?

Comment: What is that error? Remove cycle recoverable y r u using that??

Comment: just copy paste the code which I have shown you and do only the following changes:

In Input Handler class:

replace your_int_value by the variable in which you have your int value.

In Game World class:

Replace Default_Value by a number like 0, 1, 2 etc.

Do only these changes do not do any thing other than this. Then use position where you need to use your int variable in Game World class.

Comment: http://puu.sh/gzVAY/2e6f53429c.png im still getting the same errors !! ..
it says create new class ... called sharedPreferences

Comment: you know what give me your email i send you my teamviewer :) its a long code